# displaying TRUE when shiny files are split into different folders

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app using the package shinydashboard.

At first, I had all the files as 3 files - global.R, server.R, ui.R.

As files got bigger and messy, I took out the codes for each menus, and placed them in a separate folder.
(splitting shiny files - http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)

everything works, but there's something annoying happening - it displays 'TRUE' at the bottom of the ui of the menus I split into separate folder.

If everything is just in one big file, it doesn't display TRUE.

anyone know why this is happening?

functionally, everything is same.

Comment: I don't even get a true-value return. Insted I get this error message: ERROR: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What's happening is that `source` returns a list with 2 things inside: `value` which is the actual R code inside, and `visible` which is whether or not the code returned visibly or invisibly.  The `TRUE` you are seeing is a reflection of the fact that the code returned visibly.

What you want to do is include the `value` of that list. So instead of

```
source("file.R", local = TRUE)
```

Change it to

```
source("file.R", local = TRUE)$value
```

That should fix it

Comment: thanks, where do i find more documentation about things like this?

Comment: I just figured it out from manual debugging. I wasn't sure why `TRUE` is being returned, so I assigned `source(...)` to a variable and looked what that variable holds inside it. I noticed it has those two elements. I then read what the `visible` return value means and then tried changing it to be `FALSE` and saw that indeed now `FALSE` is being printed, so I tried explicitly using the `value` and it worked

Comment: Thanks @daattali! 
(Is that a bug or normal behavior? I've seen that you left a comment on rstudio scoping article, great)

Comment: I suppose that's normal behaviour