# Shiny - How to separate the Rendering functions into different files?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I separate the [Rendering functions](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/) into different files?

For instance,

I have this in my server.R,

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

   output$text <- renderUI({...})

   output$annotations <- renderDataTable({...})

   output$plot <- renderPlot({...})

}))
```

Can I put `output$text`, `output$annotations`, and `output$plot` into **separate r files** and then import them in?

My attempt,

```
source('source/server/getRenderUI.R', local = TRUE)
output$text <- getRenderUI()
```

Result,

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :    Operation not
>   allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something
>   that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: Take a look at this question, might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534674/displaying-true-when-shiny-files-are-split-into-different-folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to call `getRenderUI()`, you could try this

```
In getRenderUI.R

  output$text <- renderUI({...})

In server.R 

  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    source('...../getRenderUI.R', local = TRUE)$value

 }))
```

For me , this works well.

Note: Pay attention not to use the same name for output$xxx, because all variables is in the same scope