# Implement R-Files from subfolders into Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to stick with the KISS (keep it simple, stupid) principle within my shiny app (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-key-software-principles-you-must-understand--net-25161).

So I created a folder and subfolders and saved peaces of my code uses in the `server.R` into functions and `.R` files.
Here two examples of two saved `.R` files:

```
output$myChoices <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = 'x', 
                label = 'y', 
                choices = levels(myDataSet$df$z),
                multiple = T
    )
})
```

or

```
absoluteMatrix <- reactive({
    lifeChar <- switch(as.integer(input$something),
                   "abc",
                   "def",
                   "ghi",
                   "jkl",
                   "mno"
     )

     if( (myBoolean$absolute == TRUE) && (length(input$xy) != 0) ){

        if( (length(input$gh) == 0) ) {
            return(myData()[,grepl(lifeChar, names(myData()))] %>% 
                       na.omit %>% 
                       as.matrix)

        } else if( (length(input$gh) != 0) ) {
            return(myDataX()[,grepl(lifeChar, names(myDataX()))] %>% 
                       na.omit %>% 
                       as.matrix)
        } 
    }
})
```

In the `server.R` I wrote the following

```
library(shiny)
source("onLoad.R")

  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

     sourceRecursive("/.../")

 })
```

In the `onLoad.R` file the function `sourceRecursive` is defined:

```
 #check folder and all subfolders for .R files
 #source() them! 
 sourceRecursive <- function(path) {
      dirs <- list.dirs()
      files <- dir(pattern = "^.*[Rr]$", include.dirs = FALSE)
      for (f in files)
          source(f)
      for (d in dirs)
          sourceRecursive(d)
   }
```

But, that did not do the trick. It seems that it does not load the files or there might problems with the `reactivity` of their content.

Comment: Could you try adding 'local=TRUE' to your source() function?

Comment: I think here you can find a is a good explanation of how use multiple files with your shiny app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534674/displaying-true-when-shiny-files-are-split-into-different-folders/30538596#30538596

Comment: @BogdanRau that did the trick! Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help! Added as an answer so we can close it off. Mind confirming it?

Answer (score 0):

add 'local = TRUE' to the source() function.