# Using the source command in Rshiny without TRUE evaluation

Tags: r, shiny

When making larger applications in `RShiny` I like to keep my code in separate files for separate tabs or menus. When I place `RShiny` commands within a `.R` file and call it using the `source()` command, a `TRUE` is printed below the UI element. I have tried calling source in both `ui.R` and using `uiOutput()` as well as `invisible()`.

How do I stop the `TRUE` rendering?

**Example:**

app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(h4("Attempt 1"),
                source("TestSource.R",local=T),
                h4("Attempt 2"),
                uiOutput("at2"),
                h4("Attempt 3"),
                invisible(source("TestSource.R")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$at2 <- renderUI({
    invisible(source(
      "TestSource.R",
      verbose = F,
      echo = F,
      print.eval = F,
      prompt.echo = F,
      local = T
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

TestSource.R

```
helpText("This is a test")
```

Here is what this renders

[image: An example output]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `invisible(source("TestSource.R"))` ?

Comment: Yes, that also doesn't work.

Comment: `{source("TestSource.R");NULL}` ?

Comment: Just tried that, also no.

Comment: use `source("TestSource.R", local=TRUE)$value`

Comment: That worked! Would you like to post that as an answer or should I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `source("TestSource.R", local=TRUE)$value`

A good explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538596/4322318)

Comment: Thank you, I'm surprised I didn't find that question in my searching!

Comment: Sometimes it happens, actually I have that answer bookmarked. We still need humans.

Answer (score 1):

the source function produces a list:

```
List of 2
 $ value  :List of 3
  ..$ name    : chr "span"
  ..$ attribs :List of 1
  .. ..$ class: chr "help-block"
  ..$ children:List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr "This is a test"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 $ visible: logi TRUE
```

so you can try:

```
source("TestSource.r")[1]
```