# R Shiny - Tab Panel displays an unexpected "TRUE" message

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem while sourcing a R script inside a tabsetPanel layer :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Open Medic"),

 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Tab1", source("src/ui/1-tab1_ui.R"))                   
               ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  source("src/server/1-myserver.R", local = T)
}
```

This code always displays a "TRUE" message. I don't have any problem if I dont use a "source" instruction.

The result can be seen there :

[Problem with shiny tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCZsW.png)

EDIT : 
The 1-tab1_ui.R content is shown below :

```
 mainPanel(  helpText("Here is the problematic message :") )
```

While the server.R is actually an empty "toy" file

Comment: We can't really help you without knowing what's in `src/ui-server/...` since the problem may coming from there. On a sidenote, you should consider using [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) instead of sourcing files.

Comment: Hi. I have edited my question with the content of my files.

Comment: You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534674/displaying-true-when-shiny-files-are-split-into-different-folders)

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly ! And thanks for the advice regarding modules