# Read R code from a file (i.e. source) in a shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I want to modularise my shiny app code, by moving parts of the code in separate files. I then include the content of the file with a call to the `source` function: `source("./www/some_code.R", local = TRUE)`

It works well except for an undesired effect: the word `TRUE` is added just below the insert.

Could you help me understand why this happen and how I can remove this undesired text?

For a reproducible example,

create `app.R`:

```
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         source("./www/slider.R", local = TRUE)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and in the `www` folder the `slider.R`:

```
sliderInput("bins",
            "Number of bins:",
            min = 1,
            max = 50,
            value = 30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just when I posted this, I saw a link to this which answer the question: [displaying TRUE when shiny files are split into different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534674/displaying-true-when-shiny-files-are-split-into-different-folders)

I thought that I did my research though... Should I delete the whole thread?

Comment: There's nothing like hitting *"Ask Question"* that triggers one last successful search. Over to you.